# predict a word from collection of words

Tags: node.js, azure, api, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I want to upload an image and use image recognition to know what is the image uploaded. Instead of retrieving tags for the objects on image, I want to what is the image directly.

Or are there any APIs that collect the tags of objects of an image recognized and predict to know the image uploaded?

For example, I upload a coffee image and the expected output coffee, instead of the following tags: door, windows, tables, people etc…

I hope you understand what I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the official doc:

> Computer Vision can analyze an image and generate a human-readable
> phrase that describes its contents. The algorithm returns several
> descriptions based on different visual features, and each description
> is given a confidence score. The final output is a list of
> descriptions ordered from highest to lowest confidence.

Code sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/image-analysis-client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=visual-studio#analyze-image

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-describing-images